# Can't seem to disable Windows 7 password complexity requirements

Tags: windows-7, password-management

So, even though this is the security policy I set for one machine:

[image]

When trying to set passwords they still have to be over 16 characters and meet other various complexity requirements such as having a symbol.

The image used for this machine is Windows 7 Enterprise and not part of a domain (says workgroup is WORKGROUP, though it may have been on a domain at some point when the image was created), however I can't seem to disable the password requirements.

Additionally I've tried resetting the policy using the following commands:

```
RD /S /Q "%WinDir%\System32\GroupPolicyUsers"

RD /S /Q "%WinDir%\System32\GroupPolicy"

gpupdate /force
```

to no avail.

What am I missing here that still enforces password requirements?

Comment: Are you sure the users are not logging into the domain?  The fact you are not adjusting the local policies seems strange

Comment: So it works on this machine? Why not show us a machine where you are having issues?

Comment: The machines are standalone and we're given an admin account to use on them. The settings don't seem to be working on this machine, I posted the image to show that the settings say something other than what's being enforced.

Comment: @Ramhound Do you know an explicit way to tell if they are on a domain? When I try to join a domain it says it's on a workgroup and the domain circle isn't checked.

Comment: @Bob - Why are they part of a workgroup if they are standalone?  If the password requirements match the domain then ... I have to think about one.

Comment: They come that way, I wasn't aware you could have a Windows machine that doesn't specify either a workgroup (e.g. WORKGROUP) or domain.

Comment: @Ramhound: Technically if they are in a WORKGROUP, they are "stand alones" aka NOT part of a domain.

Comment: @surfasb - My experience of Workgroup is hooking Windows 98/95 machines together and thus they were noot standalone.

Comment: I said in the question they are standalones... Regardless, the issue here is really the password complexity requirements. I listed the workgroup information in case it would help.

Comment: @Ramhound those are still standalone - a workgroup is nothing more than a shared identifier between machines, it doesn't actually link anything. The fact that a workgroup exists means they're not in a domain and thus standalone for these purposes.